# Is there anyway to get an index of a key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

This is my question prompt:
"Write a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season. The input is a string to represent the month and an int to represent the day.

Ex: If the input is:

April
11
the output is:

Spring"

This is my code so far:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

    
days_in_year = list(range(1, 366))

months_dict = {
    
    "January": 31,
    "February": 28,
    "March": 31,
    "April": 30,
    "May": 31,
    "June": 30,
    "July": 31,
    "August": 31,
    "September": 30,
    "October": 31,
    "November": 30,
    "December": 31, 
}

if input_month in months_dict:
    test = months_dict.get(input_month)
```

My question is:
Let's say I got "March" as my month input, I want to calculate the values of the previous months in the dictionary prior to March. Ex, 31 + 28 + 12 (assuming 12 is the input_day).

How would I be able to calculate this?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indices, however a `list(months_dict.items())` *does*.

Comment: Why do you need the index? Just iterate until the month is March.

Comment: I wouldn't use a dictionary but it's doable. Have you thought about a list of days in the months? Lists are ordered and good for summing to a certain index. You could maybe covert the month to an index in that list, sum up all the values before that month and finally add the input_day?